# Stop propagation of click event on href

Tags: javascript, dom-events, href

How can I stop the propagation of the click event so that the browser will NOT redirect?

```
<a id="theHref" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">SO</a>
<script>
    document.getElementById("theHref").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
        console.log("href clicked, lets try to stop event propagation");
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, you want to listen on the "click" event, not mousedown

```
document.getElementById("theHref").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log("href clicked, lets try to stop event propagation");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

not sure you need the return false - I can never remember cross browser nuances like that :p return false does NOT stop Firefox, for instance

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work (tried in FF and in Chrome). I've updated my question with your recommendation

Comment: You're still listening to "mousedown", rather than "click"

Comment: You are right. Listening to "click" solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just try by using return false that is the simple method which will not make you redirect

```
<script>
$(function(){   
$("#theHref").click(function(){
  return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Just refer this fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nhktocy/)

Comment: jQuery return false in event handlers is the same as event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
document.getElementById("theHref").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log("href clicked, lets try to stop event propagation");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```